# Cannot Start GUIX Daemon

Tags: failed-installation, guix

I've followed all the steps in the installation of GUIX at https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/html_node/Binary-Installation.html#Binary-Installation but when I run

```
sudo ln -sf ~root/.guix-profile/lib/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service      /etc/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl enable guix-daemon
```

it errors as

```
Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

The contents of `~root/.guix-profile/lib/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service` looks correct. Only one symbolic link is involved.

What's wrong?

**Update**: I solved it by copying the file as

```
sudo cp -f ~root/.guix-profile/lib/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service      /etc/systemd/system/
```

instead. It seems there's a limitation on the number of symbolic links.

**Update**: Next problem:

The command

```
sudo systemctl start guix-daemon
```

doesn't printing anything on stdout but the daemon is not created:

```
ps -fel|grep guix
```

returns nothing.

Comment: I believe this belongs in SuperUser space. Can somebody else move it?

Comment: Does /etc/systemd/system/guix-daemon.service exist?